# Poor image quality when uploading same image with selenium using java

Tags: java, selenium

I am getting bad image quality when I upload image using selenium with java.

Here is a code:

```
imagePair.setFileLocation(downloadImage1(imagePair.getUrl()));
webElement.sendKeys(imagePair.getFileLocation());
driver.findElement(By.name("button1")).click()
```

Image pair is just a pojo that holds information what URL should be image downloaded from and where that image is stored after download (filesystem). Downloaded image quality is as good as it should be.

After click is executed image is uploaded.

Did anyone else had the same issue?

This is my configuration of driver:

```
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().version("79.0.3945.36").setup();

    ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--no-sandbox");

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
    try {
        test(driver);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
    }
    driver.close();
```

If I do the same steps manually then quality of the image is as good as it should be.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: you don't show the markup or how you get "webelement"... so it's hard to say.  Are you sure it's the same path and file?

Comment: It is the same since it is only one file input type. I am testing if website is downgrading quality but there are couple of iteration so it is time consuming testing. I will answer here once I find out. Btw, I find element by name (3rd row in first source block). Thank you for your reply.

Comment: where does webElement come from in second line? "webElement.sendKeys"  I still suspect the path/file on your end.  You sure it's the same in both cases? (manual vs automated?)

Comment: I just had an opportunity to test properly and indeed website reduces the quality of the image so there is nothing I can do really. It does not matter if I upload it using selenium or manually, it is the same low quality outcome. Thank you for your help!